# Stuck in oop code

Tags: php, oop

I found this code in a library. Can anyone please help me what this means?

```
public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository){
    $this->repository = $userRepository;
}
```

Comment: Can you please mention error as well. Or what help you needed?

Comment: I didn't get any error. I just didn't understand the thing which is inside construct parenthesis. What we call it?

Comment: See [type hinting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

Comment: read the fine manual, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

__construct is the constructor of its containing [class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) - function that's going to get called 
when you instantiate *(create a new object of the class)*.

(UserRepository $userRepository) the argument/parameter that must be sent to the constructor, in
this case type hinting is used, which means the object you send to your constructor must be of type
UserRepository or at least inherit from UserRepository.

Judging by the name of the variable passed to the constructor, I would guess you will want to read 
up a bit on the [Repository Pattern](http://css.dzone.com/books/practical-php-patterns/practical-php-patterns-8).

Sources

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 1):

The object to which has this method is initalized using another object of type UserRepository[1]

```
public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository){
```

It save  for further use is parameter.

```
$this->repository = $userRepository;
```

The __construct[2] function is called whenever you use a `new Object()`, `new Object($RepositoryObject)` in your case, instruction to instanziate a class into a variable.

Said that, the constructor is a base of the oop paradigm, you should invest some of your time to learn some on it (or how php enforce the oop paradigm[3]) in order to code with proficiency

References:

[1]http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php
[2]http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php
[3]http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php